# How to migrate log4j Logger.getAppender(String) call to v2.6?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Our project uses log4j 1.2. We are migrating it to use log4j 2.6. The migration document at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html was very helpful but does not appear to address this specific situation.

The following code was working under log4j 1.2:

```
// First, issue some messages using logging framework...
Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
myLogger.info("foobar");
// Now, verify messages went through custom appender correctly....
MyAppenderSkeletonImpl appender = (MyAppenderSkeletonImpl) myLogger.getAppender("myLogAppender");
Assert.assertNotNull(appender); // if the appender was configured properly, it won't be null
File tempFile = appender.keepTempFile(true);
Assert.assertNotNull(tempFile); // if the appender was configured properly, it won't have a null tempfile
// Finally, open the temp file and check its contents for expected messages
...
```

The line which is giving us trouble as there is no "getAppender" method on the Logger object in in v2.6.

What is the right way to think about this? What we're trying to do is verify (inside a unit test) that our custom logger was created correctly and that logs sent there are actually in the resulting file. The point of this test is to verify that the custom Appender is working properly.